# Difference between (auto) properties initialization syntax in C# 6

Tags: c#, properties, c#-6.0

What is the difference between the following expressions for initializing the properties in C# 6:

**1. Auto-Property initialized from constructor**

```
public class Context1
{
    public Context1()
    {
        this.Items = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

**2: Property initialized from a backing field**

```
public class Context2
{
    private readonly List<string> items;

    public Context2()
    {
        this.items = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.items;
        }
    }
}
```

**3: Auto-Property new syntax in C# 6**

```
public class Context3
{
    public List<string> Items { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```

**4: Auto-Property new syntax in C# 6**

```
public class Context4
{
    public List<string> Items => new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Listing 3 is C# 6's equivalent of listing 2, where the backing field is provided under the hood.

Listing 4:

```
public List<string> Items => new List<string>();
```

is equivalent to:

```
public List<string> Items { get { return new List<string>(); } }
```

which as you can imagine returns a new empty list every time you access the property.

The difference between listings 2/3 and 4 is further explored in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910985/what-is-the-difference-between-getter-only-auto-properties-and-expression-body-p) with an example.

Listing 1 is just an auto property with a getter and a private setter. It's not a readonly property in that you can set it anywhere you can access any of the type's private members. A readonly property (that is, a getter-only property) can *only* be initialized either in a constructor or in the property declaration, much like a readonly field.

Comment: So number 4 is like a Constant but with a reference type!?

Comment: If by "constant" you mean "constantly returns a new instance of this value" (à la https://xkcd.com/221), then... uh, I guess so. But that's not what "constant" means. There is a reason reference types *can't* be constants.

Comment: Are number 1 and 2 similar?

Answer (score 4):

**Auto-property** is a short designation for **auto-implemented property**, where the developer doesn't need to explicitly declare the backing field and the compiler sets one up behind the scenes.

## 1. Auto-Property with private setter

```
public class Context1
{
    public Context1()
    {
        this.Items = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

Auto-properties can have different accessibilities for setter and getter by specifying a more restrictive accessibility for the accessor for which the accessibility differs from the property's accessibility.

Other examples are:

```
public string Prop1 { get; private set; }
public string Prop2 { get; protected set; }
public string Prop3 { get; internal set; }
public string Prop4 { protected internal get; set; }
```

These accessors with different accessibility can be accessed for anywhere the that accessibility determines, not just from the constructor.

## 2. Read-only property with backing field

public class Context2
{
    private readonly List items;

```
public Context2()
{
    this.items = new List<string>();
}

public List<string> Items
{
    get { return this.items; }
}
```

}
Prior to **C#6**, the only way to set the value of a read-only property was to explicitly declare the backing field and set it directly.

Because the field has the `readonly` accessor, it can only be set during the construction of the object.

## 3. Read-Only Auto-Property

```
public class Context3
{
    public List<string> Items { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Starting with **C#6**, §2 can be handled by the compiler by have an backing field generated like for read-write auto-properties but, in this case, the backing field is read-only and can only be set during the construction of the object.

## 4. Read-only Auto-Property with expression bodied getter

```
public class Context4
{
    public List<string> Items => new List<string>();
}
```

When properties have a value that changes every time it is get, **C#6** allows to declare the body of the getter using a *lambda-like* syntax.

The above code is equivalent to this:

```
public class Context4
{
    public List<string> Items
    {
        get { return new List<string>(); }
    }
}
```