# How do i initialise a property on a class in C# 6

Tags: c#, properties, initialization, c#-6.0

I have a class that uses some services. I need each service to be instantiated on creation of the class. In C# 6 I can see 2 ways of doing this but I'm not sure which would be correct...

```
protected static SomeServiceType Service => new SomeServiceType();
```

alternatively I could use an autoproperty initialiser...

```
protected static SomeServiceType Service { get;} = new SomeServiceType();
```

What are the advantages/drawbacks with each approach?
Many thanks

Comment: First one is not correct. => is lambda expression syntax.

Comment: @Andry [New in C# 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

Comment: You can try things out and see how it translates at http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net

Comment: @Rawling it is still a lamba expression. It is not value.

Comment: @Andrey Ah, I see what you mean. It's valid C#, but it's not right for what Simon wants. My apologies.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910985

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe

- the former ("Expression-bodied members") calls `new SomeServiceType()` *every time the property is read*
- the latter ("Auto-property initializers") calls it *once* on instantiation, and returns the created instance every time the property is read.

It sounds like you want the latter.